# I cannot upload images to post or the media library in wordpress

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

Whenever I try to upload featured image for a new post or edit featured image of the older post, the following errors comes up:

> An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

Here I have attached screenshots,[image]

Comment: Check in the Browser console, there should be an error. That will tell you about it is. Post the error here.

Comment: Also, add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` and `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` to your `/wp-config.php` above the line that says "Stop editing". This will create a file in `/wp-content/debug.log` that may have some errors after trying to upload again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `wp-content/uploads` directory is writable.

In Ubuntu, open the terminal, then type

```
chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
```

Adjust that command to your WordPress installation directory. Then, try again.

Comment: `777` will give access to everyone which is quite huge security problem. You better go with `755`.